# tkinter tooltip quite always not showing in Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: tkinter, tooltip

Trying the first basilar example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tktooltip import ToolTip

app = tk.Tk()
b = ttk.Button(app, text="Button")
b.pack()
ToolTip(b, msg="Hover info")
app.mainloop()
```

with Python 3.12.2, tkinter-tooltip 3.0.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise, tooltips are not displayed in most cases. Sometimes, they appear in random attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I found that your coding is working well linux. Also With your experiments, We may have to conclude that the problem occurs in windows

Tooltip module's official document says`Certain options do not match great with each other, a good example is follow and delay using small x/y offsets. This can cause the tooltip to appear inside the widget. Hovering over the tooltip will cause it to disappear and reappear, in a new position, potentially again inside the widget.` [The proof of Screenshot is given here](https://imgur.com/MTyFObY).

So, I just thought of bringing the same result in tkinter without using the tooltip module. And it is successful. Kindly try in your windows PC.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def popup(wdgt, txt):
    pop = tk.Toplevel(wdgt)
    pop.overrideredirect(True)
    
    tk.Label(pop, text = txt).pack()
    wdgt.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: pop.destroy())
    x_center =b.winfo_rootx() + b.winfo_width() 
    y_center = b.winfo_rooty() + b.winfo_height()
    pop.geometry(f"+{x_center}+{y_center}")


def make_tt(wdgt, txt):
    
    wdgt.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: popup(wdgt,txt))

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('200x300')
b = ttk.Button(app, text="Button")
b.pack()

app.after_idle(lambda : make_tt(b, 'Hover Info'))
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The form created by the code is very simple with only one button. You can raise the window dimention but nothing changes. I confirm that it works perfectly also on Cygwin/X server but not on Windows.

Comment: @Luca, See my edited answer and the solution.

Comment: @Luca, I deleted the previous answer and created a new one see if it is useful

Comment: I would like to thank you very much, I have already seen your reply and replied myself!! youa are great

Answer (score 0):

Great! you solved my problem!

Following, the code revised as to make possible to have multiple tooltips for more than one button.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def popup(wdgt, txt):
    pop = tk.Toplevel(wdgt)
    pop.overrideredirect(True)

    tk.Label(pop, text = txt).pack()
    wdgt.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: pop.destroy())
    x_center =wdgt.winfo_rootx() + wdgt.winfo_width() 
    y_center = wdgt.winfo_rooty() + wdgt.winfo_height()
    pop.geometry(f"+{x_center}+{y_center}")


def make_tt(wdgt, txt):

    wdgt.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: popup(wdgt,txt))

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('200x300')
b = ttk.Button(app, text="Button")
b.pack()

app.after_idle(lambda : make_tt(b, 'Hover Info'))
app.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much again!!
Luca